Prove the a set C is the field by showing the finite union of element in C is also in C
Suppose Q and P are product measure. $P,Q$ is on $(E_1\times E_2, a_1\otimes a_2$) . $P_1$ is on $(E_1,a_1)$, and $P_2$ is on  $(E_2,a_2)$. $Q(A_1\times A_2)=P_1(A_1)P_2(A_2)=P(A_1\times A_2)$
Suppose $R=\{A_1\times A_2 : A_1\in a_1, A_2\in a_2\}$, and $C=(c\in \sigma(R): P(c)=Q(c))$.
How to prove that C is field? I actually want to prove C is the $\sigma$-field. However, before I apply monotone class theorem, I have to prove C is the field first.
Here is my incomplete and unsuccessful proof on C is field:
Suppose $c_1, c_2\in C$. Then $c_1\cup c_2\in \sigma (R)$. $P(c_1\cup c_2)=P(c_1)+P(c_2)-P(c_1\cap c_2)$, and $Q(c_1\cup c_2)=Q(c_1)+P(c_2)-Q(c_1\cap c_2)$. We know $P(c_1)=Q(c_1)$ and $P(c_2)=Q(c_2)$. However, we cannot determine $Q(c_1\cap c_2)=P(c_1\cap c_2)$. I feel like I am on the loop.

It is not clear what you are asking. If both $P$ and $Q$ are the product measure on $E_1 \times E_2$, then they are equal everywhere, so obviously $C = \sigma(R)$. Do you mean only $P$ is the product measure and $Q$ is some other measure which agrees with $P$ on the sets in $R$? Also, I think you mean "$\sigma$-algebra", not "$\sigma$-field". At least, I do not know what "$\sigma$-field" would mean here.

That said, $c_1, c_2$ are unions of "rectangles". The intersection of two rectangles is also a rectangle.

Our book denotes " -algebra" as "-field". I actually want to prove that there only exists a unique product measure. I set both $P,Q$ are on $(E_1\times E_2, a_1\otimes a_2$). Then, I want to test whether  P = Q are same in every elements  $\sigma(R)$. This is the reason why I set $C=(c\in \sigma(R): P(c)=Q(c))$. If $C=\sigma(R)$, then P and Q are same. However, before proving that $C=\sigma(R)$, I have to prove $C$ is the field before apply monotone class theorem.
